# Limit Cart Items to Add in Cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I want to limit cart items to be added in cart.
Limit Checkout Order or Add to Cart Limit to allow only 6 type of items.
These 6 items can have variable Qty value.

I have done the below code using Event/Observer but not working.

`etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="ishaq_limit_items_in_cart_checkout_before" instance="Ishaq\LimitCartItems\Observer\Checkout\Cart\Add" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`Observer/Checkout/Cart/Add.php`

```
<?php

namespace Ishaq\LimitCartItems\Observer\Checkout\Cart;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface as ResponseRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;

class Add implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var Session $session */
    private $session;

    /** @var ActionFlag $flag */
    private $flag;

    /** @var ResponseRedirect $redirect */
    private $redirect;

    /** @var MessageManager $messageManager */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * Add constructor.
     *
     * @param Session          $session
     * @param ActionFlag       $flag
     * @param ResponseRedirect $redirect
     * @param MessageManager   $messageManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        ResponseRedirect $redirect,
        MessageManager $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_request        = $request;
        $this->_cart           = $cart;
        $this->redirect        = $redirect;
        $this->messageManager  = $messageManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     *
     * @return $this|void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $postValues = $this->_request->getPostValue();
        $cartQuote = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getData();
        $cartItemsCount = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
        $cartItemsAll = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
 
        if($cartItemsCount > 6)
        {
            $observer->getRequest()->setParam('product', false);
            $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            $observer->getRequest()->setParam('backUrl', $this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Only 6 types of products per purchase allowed. Please complete this order first and place another order afterwards.')
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer below module. https://github.com/eeree/magento-limit-items-quantity-in-cart/tree/master/src/app . Though it is for Magento 1 you will get an idea. They have used the event catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options

Comment: do you want that user only purchase 6 qty per order?

Comment: I want six products to be added to the cart despite products quantity, products can have variable quantity. @JigsParmar

Answer (score 0):

you need to change if condition by

```
if(count($cartItemsAll) > 6)
```

Comment: This is not about quantity, I am talking about products, the quantity may vary for each product. But only 6 products are allowed in one order.

Comment: did you put log in your file and check file is call or not?

Comment: One Checkout/AddCart Maximum 6 Items:
ItemA 25Qty, ItemB 125Qty, ItemC Sample, ItemD 50Qty, ItemE 100Qty, ItemF Sample,

Comment: did you put log in your file and check file is call or not?

Comment: Yes , ```$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
  $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
  $logger->addWriter($writer);
  $logger->info("Ishaq" );``` But these logs not working

Comment: i update my code please try that in if condition and let me know its working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118583/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-ishaq).